# VueJS change font of specific row not all rows

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Current code changes the font for all rows vs a specific row:

```js
Vue.component('blog-post', {
  props: ['post'],
  template: `
    <div class="blog-post row">
      <h3 class="cell"> {{ post.title }}</h3>
      <button @click="$emit('enlarge-text')">Enlarge text</button>
      <div v-html="post.content" class="cell"></div>
    </div>
  `,
});

new Vue({
  el   : '#blog-post-demo',
  data : {
    posts : [
      {id: 1, title : 'My Journey to Africa',    content : 'I am the post'},
      {id: 2, title : 'My Journey to America',   content : 'I am the post'},
      {id: 3, title : 'My Journey to Antartica', content : 'I am the post'},
      {id: 4, title : 'My Journey to Asia',      content : 'I am the post'},
    ],
    postFontSize : 1,
  }
});
```

```css
.row {
  background-color: cyan;
}

.cell {
  background-color: antiquewhite;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="blog-post-demo">
  <blog-post v-for="post in posts" :post="post" :key="post.id" :style="{fontSize : postFontSize + 'em'}" @enlarge-text="postFontSize += 0.1"></blog-post>
</div>
```

How can I just manipulate a specific row, one row, updating one row's font size vs all rows?

Tried the following but it did not work:

```js
Vue.component('blog-post', {
  props: ['post'],
  template: `
    <div class="blog-post row" :style="{fontSize : postFontSize + 'em'}" @enlarge-text="postFontSize += 0.1">
      <h3 class="cell">{{ post.title }}</h3>
      <button @click="$emit('enlarge-text')">Enlarge text</button>
      <div v-html="post.content" class="cell"></div>
    </div>
  `,
});

new Vue({
  el   : '#blog-post-demo',
  data : {
    posts : [
      {id: 1, title : 'My Journey to Africa',    content : 'I am the post'},
      {id: 2, title : 'My Journey to America',   content : 'I am the post'},
      {id: 3, title : 'My Journey to Antartica', content : 'I am the post'},
      {id: 4, title : 'My Journey to Asia',      content : 'I am the post'},
    ],
    postFontSize : 1,
  }
})
```

```css
.row {
  background-color: cyan;
}

.cell {
  background-color: antiquewhite;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="blog-post-demo">
  <blog-post v-for="post in posts" :post="post" :key="post.id"></blog-post>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to update only 1 row, `postFontSize` should be local data of `blog-post` component

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>My first Vue app</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <style>
    .row {
      background-color: cyan;
    }

    .cell {
      background-color: antiquewhite;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="blog-post-demo">
      <blog-post v-for="post in posts" :post="post" :key="post.id"></blog-post>
    </div>
  <script>
    
Vue.component('blog-post', {
  props: ['post'],
  template: `
    <div class="blog-post row" :style="{fontSize : postFontSize + 'em'}">
      <h3 class="cell"> {{ post.title }}</h3>
      <button @click="postFontSize += 0.1">Enlarge text</button>
      <div v-html="post.content" class="cell"></div>
    </div>`,
  data() {
     return {
          postFontSize : 1
     }
  }
})
new Vue({
  el   : '#blog-post-demo',
  data : {
    posts : [
      {id: 1, title : 'My Journey to Africa',    content : 'I am the post'},
      {id: 2, title : 'My Journey to America',   content : 'I am the post'},
      {id: 3, title : 'My Journey to Antartica', content : 'I am the post'},
      {id: 4, title : 'My Journey to Asia',      content : 'I am the post'},
    ]
  }
})
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the difference between having `postFontSize` in the `data` variable that is inside the `new Vue` vs `data` inside the component?

Answer (score 1):

The reason your first code snippet does not work is because you placed the `postFontSize` variable at its parent component. That's why all children component will share the same variable, meaning one changes in variable will affect every child.

To fix the problem, simply move all variables related to `blog-post` component into `blog-post` component (not in its parent component).

This includes `postFontSize`, `@click` method, and `:style` declaraction:

```js
Vue.component('blog-post', {
  template: `
    <div class="blog-post row" :style="{ fontSize: postFontSize + 'em' }">
      <h3 class="cell">{{ post.title }}</h3>
      <button @click="enlargeText">Enlarge text</button>
      <div v-html="post.content" class="cell"></div>
    </div>
  `,
  props: ['post'],
  data: function(){
    return {
      postFontSize: 1
    }
  },
  methods: {
    enlargeText: function(){
      this.postFontSize += 0.1;
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el   : '#blog-post-demo',
  data : {
    posts : [
      {id: 1, title : 'My Journey to Africa',    content : 'I am the post'},
      {id: 2, title : 'My Journey to America',   content : 'I am the post'},
      {id: 3, title : 'My Journey to Antartica', content : 'I am the post'},
      {id: 4, title : 'My Journey to Asia',      content : 'I am the post'},
    ]
  }
});
```

```css
.row {
  background-color: cyan;
}

.cell {
  background-color: antiquewhite;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="blog-post-demo">
  <blog-post v-for="post in posts" :post="post" :key="post.id"></blog-post>
</div>
```

Comment: What's the difference between having `postFontSize` in the `data` variable that is inside the `new Vue` vs `data` inside the component?

Comment: @RobertRocha Think of `new Vue` as the global scope within Vue. When you change a global variable, everything within that scope that depends on the same global variable will be affected, because essentially there is only 1 variable to depend on. When you put that variable inside component (local scope), each component depends on their own variable. So changes outside of the local scope will not affect the component.